# Solidity function with arrays gives overflow error

Tags: arrays, overflow, solidity, remix

I have the same code without an array and it just works.
But In this one if i enter amount anything more than 0.001 ether it gives an overflow error.
I tried Other functions called in this one with errored values and they don't give an error.

CheckPairValue() and CheckSellPrice() works.

Code is to check my Wallet's worth in pancakeswap

Idk what's wrong.
Any help is appretiated.

Also Contract is verified on bscscan.
[Contract](https://www.bscscan.com/address/0xbd29c833bf3a5186df62abbcdb8542f6066a3d8f#code)

```
function GetSellValue(address[] memory TokenAddress, uint[] memory Amount)public view returns(uint256[] memory){
        uint[] memory Value = new uint[](TokenAddress.length);
        for(uint i = 0; i < TokenAddress.length; i++){
            address Pair = CheckPairValue(TokenAddress[i], Amount[i] * 2);
            address[] memory path;
            if(Pair != PairAddresses[0]){
                path = new address[](3);
                path[0] = TokenAddress[i];
                path[1] = Pair;
                path[2] = PairAddresses[0];
            }
            else
            {
                path = new address[](2);
                path[0] = TokenAddress[i];
                path[1] = PairAddresses[0];
            }
            Value[i] = CheckSellPrice(Amount[i],path);
        }
        return Value;
    }
```

[0.001 ether input works , anything higher doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxgUi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why remix errored like this.
But i've written a js code to call the contract and it works.